# Question about the Solution for Problem 3.7b, Introduction to Probability (Bertsekas, 2nd Edition)

Tags: self-study, cumulative-distribution-function

I am currently working on the problems in *Introduction to Probability (Bertsekas and Tsitsiklis, 2nd Edition)* and one of the problems is as follows:

[image]

For Problem (b), the final answer is as follows:

[image]

**My question:**

Why do we have cumulative density for *0 <= s <= 1/t*? Shouldn't the cumulative density be 0 on the *0 <= s <= 1/t* interval? Based on the problem statement, my assumption is that *s* can only be 0 or [1/t, +inf) so anything outside of that shouldn't be possible (hence, 0 probability). Am i missing something here?

Thanks in advance.

P.S The final answer is taken from the book's Problem Solutions supplement.

Comment: Welcome to CV. If this question relates to a class exercise, please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info and add the tag to modify the question accordingly.

Comment: @Pitouille. sorry I was not aware. The question is now tagged properly. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Re "Shouldn't it be 0:" What does "it" refer to??

Comment: @whuber sorry about that. I was referring to the cumulative density if  0 <= s <= 1/t. Modified the question :)

Comment: Re the edit: let me translate this.  For the CDF to be zero on the interval $[0,1/t],$ by *definition* that implies the chance of a dart hitting within a distance of $1/t$ (or less) of the center is zero.  Although that does indeed correspond to "equally likely," do you think that's what the question really means?  It does suggest an interesting interpretation in which the question is too vague to be answerable, because it says nothing about the chances of the dart hitting outside the board. Here, you have to use your "common test sense" to guess at the intended interpretation.

Comment: So my approach was to start with the values of Alvin's score (S) then map it back to the corresponding Xs (X = distance from the center) to achieve that score.

1/t < s corresponds to the instances where the dart falls between 0 and t (0 <= x <= t).
s = 0 corresponds to the instances where the dart falls beyond t (x > t).

I don't know where 0 < s <1/t is mapped to though. I don't think the problem allows these values of s.

Comment: Thank you--I had not read the question with sufficient care, and had taken $s$ to be the distance rather than the score.  It looks like the person who published the answer made the same mistake :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my approach was to start with the values of Alvin's score (S) then map it back to the corresponding Xs (X = distance from the center) to achieve that score.

This is the right approach, with one small modification: you should map back to the corresponding values of $X$ that achieve that score *or less*. That is the quantity that the CDF is referring to. Remember that $F_S(s) = P(S \leq s) = \int_{-\infty}^s f(s)ds$.

For example, under the rules in (b) there is no way to get a score of $S = \frac{1}{2t}$. But there is a way to get a score of $S \leq \frac{1}{2t}$. Any dart outside the inner circle will result in $S = 0 \leq \frac{1}{2t}$.

So score values of $0 \leq s < \frac{1}{t}$ all come from missing the inner circle, which is why the CDF has a long 'flat' section over that range.

Comment: Thank you! This made me realize the error in my thought process. Initially, I thought that the interval 0 <= s <1/t (there's even an error in my initial notation, lol) was not mapped to any Xs. This is wrong. The value 0 is included in this interval and this, as stated above, corresponds to the values of Xs farther than t (x>t).

Answer (score 0):

Let $C_x$ and $C_y$ denote the coordinates of Alvin's throw on the dart board with radius $r$.  By assumption, each point is equally likely, hence the joint density function of $C_x$ and $C_y$ is $f_{C_x,C_y}(c_x,c_y) = 1/(\pi r^2)$ such that $c_x^2+c_y^2 \le r^2$.

Let $X$ denote the distance of Alvin's hit from the center.  Clearly, $X^2 = C_x^2 + C_y^2$.  Therefore, the CDF of $X$ is
\begin{eqnarray*} 
F(X) = \mbox{Pr}\left[X \le x\right] = \mbox{Pr}\left[\sqrt{C_x^2 + C_y^2} \le x\right]=\frac{x^2}{r^2},
\end{eqnarray*}
where the penultimate equality holds since if his throw is less than $x$ units away from the center, than $C_x$ and $C_y$ must lie in this smaller circle.

Next let $S = \frac{1}{X}I[X \le t]$, where $I[\cdot]$ denotes the indicator function.  Clearly given $X \le t$, then we have a simple univariate transformation, and the PDF of $S$, given $S \ge 1/t$, is $f_S(s) = \frac{2}{y^3r^2}$.  Given $S$ is 0, it must hold that $X\ge t$.  Evaluating the probability of this event and coupling these we have,
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_S(s) = \begin{cases} 1-\frac{t^2}{r^2} & \mbox{if} \quad s = 0  \\
\frac{2}{s^3r^2} & \mbox{if} \quad s \ge 1/t
\end{cases}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Now we are ready to find the CDF of $S$.  Note, $\mbox{Pr}[S\le s] = \mbox{Pr}[S = 0] + \mbox{Pr}[1/t \le S \le s]$.  Clearly, if $S<0$, then the CDF is $0$, and if $S<1/t$ then only the first term contributes.  If $S\ge 1/t$, then we need to evaluate the second term which turns out to be
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mbox{Pr}[1/t \le S \le s] = \int_{1/t}^s \frac{2}{x^3r^2} \mbox{d}x = \frac{t^2}{r^2}-\frac{1}{s^2r^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

The result follows by combining these 3 cases as in the solution manual.

To answer your question, "Shouldn't the cumulative density be 0 on the 0 <= s <= 1/t interval?"  Recall that in the name it is CUMULATIVE.  Hence, the probability at 0, extends indefinitely.  Since there is no other change, it remains constant on this interval.